# Leiningen REPL Issue

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I just installed Leiningen 2.4.3 using the install script for my Ubuntu 14.04 system. When I attempt to use lein to enter the REPL, I get a rather nasty dump to the console:

`charles@charles-930X5J-910S5J-940X5J:~$ lein repl
nREPL server started on port 60889 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:60889
Exception in thread "nREPL-worker-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session$session_out$fn__7630.doInvoke(session.clj:43)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:460)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session.proxy$java.io.Writer$ff19274a.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
    at clojure.core$fn__5471.invoke(core_print.clj:191)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
    at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:3392)
    at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3404)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$prn.doInvoke(core.clj:3437)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$println.doInvoke(core.clj:3457)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.main$repl_caught.invoke(main.clj:158)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569$fn__7582.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:76)
    at clojure.main$repl$fn__6634.invoke(main.clj:259)
    at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:257)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:41)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__7610$fn__7613.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:171)
    at clojure.core$comp$fn__4192.invoke(core.clj:2402)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__7603.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:138)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
REPL-y 0.3.2, nREPL 0.2.0-beta5NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)#Exception in thread "nREPL-worker-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session$session_out$fn__7630.doInvoke(session.clj:43)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:460)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session.proxy$java.io.Writer$ff19274a.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
    at clojure.core$fn__5471.invoke(core_print.clj:191)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
    at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:3392)
    at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3404)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$prn.doInvoke(core.clj:3437)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$println.doInvoke(core.clj:3457)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.main$repl_caught.invoke(main.clj:158)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569$fn__7582.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:76)
    at clojure.main$repl$fn__6634.invoke(main.clj:259)
    at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:257)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:41)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__7610$fn__7613.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:171)
    at clojure.core$comp$fn__4192.invoke(core.clj:2402)
    at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__7603.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:138)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Error loading namespace; falling back to userNoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)user=>

I need some help interpreting what this means and how to fix it. Running JDK 1.8.0_20

Comment: do you have any plugins in the .lein directory perhaps?

Comment: I notice from your prompt that this is not in a project directory, but instead in your home directory. This is a known issue with lein 2.4.3 and repls outside project directories, the solution is to downgrade until a fixed version is available, see my above comment.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug with lein 2.4.3. Until a new stable version is available, it can be fixed by running the following code:
`lein upgrade 2.4.2`. Also, this problem only shows up in projectless repls, if you create a new project, and run lein from inside the project directory, the error will not occur.